# Outlook is displaying a reminder for calendar events that have not reminder set

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 for both work and personal accounts and have noticed recently (maybe last two weeks?) that both my work and my personal accounts on different computers are both showing the same problem.  I am getting a reminder notification for ALL my outlook calendar events.  Most of them do not have a reminder set on the event.  Is there a new setting I need to change for this or is this a recent bug introduced by Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Options > Calendar, under Calendar options, clear the checkbox of Default reminders.

Comment: I am not sure that will accomplish what I need.  I want to still have a default reminder of 10 minutes assigned to a new calendar event that I create.  My problem is that on some events I turn off the reminder (set to Never Remind), but I still get a reminder for those events.  That is what I want to stop.